# How could I convert a python dictionary that is encoded in bytes, into a UTF-8 Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, encoding, byte, decoding

I have the following dictionary: `pointsdict = {b'335139450613137430': b'1', b'704168692828864574': b'22'}` where the first element is the user id and the second element is points. How could I change 335139450613137430's amount of points.

I have tried

```
decoded = pointsdict.decode()
decoded[userid] = pointstoset
pointsdict = decoded.encode()
```

and have received `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'` on the first line. How can I do this?

Thanks - Evan

Comment: Can you post what the result should be? "decode" and "change amount of points" seem different to me. Also, what encoding is that? Do you want all keys and values to be strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can store the decoded items into another dictionary:

```
pointsdict = {b'335139450613137430': b'1', b'704168692828864574': b'22'}

decoded = {}

for key in pointsdict.keys():
    decoded[key.decode('ascii')] = pointsdict[key].decode('ascii')

print(decoded)
```

Output:

```
{'335139450613137430': '1', '704168692828864574': '22'}
```

---

---

---

The code can be more compacted like this:

```
decoded = {key.decode('ascii'):pointsdict[key].decode(ascii) for key in pointsdict.keys()}
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I was hoping to find a feature built into python but I guess it doesn't exist. I will use this in my project. Thanks

Comment: @EGE - This could be written a bit more compactly as `decoded = {key.decode('ascii');value.decode(ascii) for key,value in pointsdict.items()}` but its the way to do it. Decoding is not a generally useful thing for key/value pair mappings so its not builtin.